# Why is counter present after each found value?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that needs to print out multiple things: the array, the `length` of it, the type of each data in the array, the number of strings in the array and if the array contains only strings.

I managed to make a `function` that does just that.

My only question/problem is the fact that the counter for the strings, `tip` is present after each found value that matches my requirements, aka after each string.

Is there a way to avoid that? And is there any other way to solve this type of exercise?

```js
var sir = ["water", 3, true, false, "dog"]

function verificare() {
  var lungimesir = sir.length;
  document.write("this is the length of the array " + lungimesir + "<br>");
  var tip = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sir.length; i++) {
    var value = typeof(sir[i]);
    document.write(" " + value + "<br>");
    if (value === "string") {
      tip = tip + 1;
      document.write(" " + tip + "<br>");
    }

  }
  document.write("the number of strings found is " + tip + "<br>");
  if (tip === lungimesir) {
    document.write("the array contains only strings " + "<br>")
  } else {
    document.write("the array is mixed " + "<br>")
  }


}
verificare(sir);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. If you comment out `document.write(" " + tip + "<br>");` then you will not see it

Comment: if i run the code after each string value the counter `tip` is present. that was my problem. i edited it out like you said and now it works as i wanted it to. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Feel free to delete this very specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hint is that you are typing only via `document.write` calls. Since it happens once per item, the problem is probably at a single call to `document.write`. And there is a `document.write` which types `tip`. Comment out that line and the issue is resolved:

```
var sir = ["water", 3, true, false, "dog"]

function verificare() {
  var lungimesir = sir.length;
  document.write("this is the length of the array " + lungimesir + "<br>");
  var tip = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sir.length; i++) {
    var value = typeof(sir[i]);
    document.write(" " + value + "<br>");
    if (value === "string") {
      tip = tip + 1;
      //document.write(" " + tip + "<br>");
    }

  }
  document.write("the number of strings found is " + tip + "<br>");
  if (tip === lungimesir) {
    document.write("the array contains only strings " + "<br>")
  } else {
    document.write("the array is mixed " + "<br>")
  }


}
verificare(sir);
```

Comment: awesome! it worked this way. thank you also for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Delete this string :

```
document.write(" " + tip + "<br>");
```